# What is the name of this part/piece on a 2015 continental gt speed convertible 2-door coupe?

Tags: part-identification, parts, body

what is the name of this part piece circled in red?

[image: Text]

Comment: It may not have a name, but will have a part number if it is a separate part of the front skirt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air duct / air duct guide / winglet

Part number 3W8 071 612 A (right).   3W8 071 612 (Left)

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help